# Integrating $\frac{1}{a}\int{ye^{-y/a} dy}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\frac{1}{b}\int{ye^{-y/b} dy}$

Hi, I checked my answer with an online calculator but I can't understand what my mistakes is so I would appreciate it if you could it out.

Let $a = \frac{1}{b}$:

$=a\int{ye^{-ya}} dy$

Using integration by parts on $\int{ye^{-ya}}$

I got:
$ye^{-ya}+a^{-2}e^{-ya}$

$\therefore a(ye^{-ya}+a^{-2}e^{-ya})$

I substituted $\frac{1}{b}$ into $a$ again at the end which left me with the wrong answer.

Comment: You did not integrate by parts correctly.

Comment: The by parts you want to use is :
$$f(y)=y -> f'(y)=1$$
$$g'(y)=e^{-ya}->g(y)= -\frac{1}{a}e^{-ya}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating $e^{-ya}$ first we get $\int ye^{-ya}dy=-\frac 1  a ye^{-ya}+ \frac 1  a\int e^{-ya}dy+C=-\frac 1  a ye^{-ya}-\frac 1 {a^{2}} e^{-ya}+C$.

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$
I = \frac{1}{b}\int{ye^{-y/b} dy}
$$

Let $$a = \frac{1}{b}$$

Then
$$
I = a \int y e^{-ay} dy
$$

Using integration by parts, we get
$$
I =  \int y d\left[ - e^{-a y} \right] =
y \left[ - e^{-a y} \right] - \int \left[ - e^{-a y} \right] dy
$$

Simplifying, we get
$$
I = - y e^{-a y} + \int e^{-a y} \ dy
$$

Integrating, we get
$$
I = - y e^{- a y} + {e^{-a y} \over - a} + C
$$
or
$$
I = - y e^{-a y} - {1 \over a} e^{-a y} + C
$$

Since $a = {1 \over b}$, we express $I$ as
$$
I = - y e^{- {y \over b}} - b e^{- {y \over b}} + C
$$